# The system cannot find the path specified - Unity Error

Tags: unity-game-engine

so I'm new in Unity. I'm using Unity HUB 3.50 with 3 Unity Editors installed, which are 2020.3.48f1, 2021.3.27f1 and 2022.3.4f1.

So I got this error message when creating and opening an empty project:
[Error message when opening project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNruB.png)

And these errors message:
[Error messages on console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJF2O.png)

My Editor installaation location is in D:\Unity Hub\EDITOR. And the project in D:\UnityProject.

I've tried some tutorials to fix this problem but none of them worked. From using another version of Unity Hub and Unity Editor, run the program as administrator, move the installation directory, disabling antivirus & firewall and installing stuff on package manager.

I also found solution to do some changes on registry editor: [Solution to edit Registry Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCaHD.png)
but I couldn't find Command Processor folder on both steps.

Comment: what exactly does the error message say?

Comment: is there any chance drive D is your one drive area or apple drive or something?

Answer (score 0):

Previously, I couldn't find the Command Processor on Registry Editor. But somehow when I tried again, I can find it and remove the value of autorun on:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun

After that, I can create and open the project without error messages on the console.